# Credible sources to download TrueCrypt 7.1a

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt

As the official developers of TrueCrypt discontinued the software and left the following messages on the official [website](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads)

**WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues**

I am wondering about all the multiple but **credible** sources to obtain TrueCrypt 7.1a, if I am correct this was the most common, favoured, and seen as "safest" version to use.

Ideally I am looking for 5+ credible sources which contain the software and matching hashes.

Also I believe the official TrueCrypt website used to list the hash for the corresponding download, are these hashs also visible @ some credible places? I assume the hashes and downloads must be the same @ all credible sources.

Comment: https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm is one, but as it stands a question simply asking for download links (that may not be valid tomorrow) is not on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

[The Wikipedia page for TrueCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt#End_of_life_announcement) references [this link](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm) as the final release repository for the last official TrueCrypt release before the project was killed.

Note that this link is from [Gibson Research Corporation](http://www.grc.com), a private, for-profit security research firm. I am not endorsing GRC's products in any way.

The source code for TrueCrypt is freely available, and a full audit is currently underway.  For the time being, TrueCrypt is still considered secure.  Reports that TrueCrypt has been hacked have not been substantiated.

Comment: http://istruecryptauditedyet.com - Phase 2 completed on April 2, no major issues or any backdoors found. Follow-up [here](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/04/truecrypt-security-audit-is-good-news-so-why-all-the-glum-faces/).

Comment: Thanks for the update @karan. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score -3):

Im afraid its true, TrueCrypt has been cracked according to a number of official sources and is no longer considered a secure means to encrypt emails and such.

PGP ( Pretty Good Protection ) used to be one of the better ways to encrypt stuff as it had a key sent first then the message and without both emails then you couldnt decrypt it.

If I send anything that needs to be encrypted, i pack it in a RAR file with a password and phone the recipient and give them the password or send it in a text message way more secure these days. Winrar is cheap enough to buy and easy enough to use with files of any size.

This is advice and should be taken as such

Comment: Lol you must be joking. None of what you said is advice to me. My opinion is that truecrypt has not been cracked, I believe the authors were coerced into taking it down as it was too good a protection for the public and was(still is) causing the police, FBI, NSA, etc many problems when any user uses a strong password.

Comment: The recent security audit of TC7.1a didn't find any major issues, although there are niggles and a few bugs that are being addressed by forks such as VeraCrypt and others.

Comment: I know a few guys who spend every day of their lives in the online security business, Truecrypt as you rightly say is being adapted by others, but when this is done on a security program, personally I leave it well alone, if someone other than the original developer is hacking into the code you cant be sure whats in there. As for credible sources, I doubt youd find one other than the main truecrypt site, the rest would just be too untrustworthy to download. Proceed with extreme caution.

Comment: TrueCrypt being cracked is a factually inaccurate statement. Please cite the numerous official sources you refer to. A full security audit of the source code is currently underway and thus far, no issues have been uncovered.

Comment: @PCDATALINCS you are not a serious person, Telling people to download from the official website shows your support for the NSA Backdoored alternative that is the ONLY download being offered there. I personally know three people who had their laptops seized and the police tried to threaten them into giving the passwords as they could not access them, 2 years later to this day the police still hold their laptops refusing to give them back until they can access them, it really shows all the "cracks" and "bugs" this program has.... LOL. Go away you fool nobody here.

Comment: @PCDATALINCS  - Provide those sources.  You make a serious statement without any proof, then suggest a method ( WinRAR ), with known provable [weaknesses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winrarpasswordremover/).

Comment: @Ramhound: That so-called password 'remover' simply seems to be brute forcing and not one-click removing any RAR password. If RAR's encryption algo was so bad we'd all know about it. Not only that, RAR5 is significantly improved in this regard so I'd love to see some proof about these supposed weaknesses. That aside, the comment above that "TrueCrypt has been cracked according to a number of official sources" is rubbish unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @Karan I know...that...still feel WinRAR password < Truecrypt anyday

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not arguing RAR's better than TC. All I'm saying is RAR is not so weak as you made it out to be.